# Rails App - Booking timeslots Schema Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, schema

I am currently building a Ruby on Rails application for students to book workshop classes with instructors. I am seeking some advice regarding the models setup.

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563459/db-schema-for-appointment-booking-app-what-is-the-correct-relationship-between) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357798/building-an-appointment-booking-system-in-rails) stack overflow threads, but they do not answer my questions.

---

**Functionality required:**

- Instructor needs to be able to set weekly-repeating timeslots available for booking
- Instructor needs to be able to open up additional one-off timeslots in addition to the weekly-repeating slots
- Instructor needs to be able to remove available timeslots on a one-off basis, e.g. when instructor goes on vacation
- Classes are not limited to one student, classes can have as many students as the teacher wishes
- All classes are one-hour long, so only start time needs to be considered

---

**My current proposal:**

I'm considering setting it up three models and three tables. The three models all connect to the same `workshop` controller.

Example data uses the following scenario: Tom has classes every Mon & Tue 9am, but for next week only, he is switching his Tue classes to be held on Wed.

The idea is that I have a model that lists all the teachers' classes. I have another model for the recurring timeslots for each of the teacher's classes. I then have a third model for exceptions that acts as a list of 'changes' to the weekly-repeating classes times:

`workshop` model linked to `workshop` table:

```
ID | Workshop Name | Price
1  | Tom's Class   | 100
```

`workshop_times_recurring` model linked to `workshop_times_recurring` table:

```
ID | Workshop ID | Times
1  | 1           | {Monday 0900, Tuesday 0900}
```

`workshop_times_other` model linked to `workshop_times_other` table:

```
ID | Workshop ID | Type    | Time
1  | 1           | Active  | {2017May31 09am}
2  | 1           | Inactive| {2017May30 09am}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is this the most elegant way to set up the models for my app and I'm not completely off-track? If not, what is a better solution?
2. I am hoping that I am able to parse strings like `'Monday 0900, Tuesday 0900'` and `'2017May31 09am'` such that information can be shown correctly on a javascript-driven datetime selection calendar. Will my current setup allow me to achieve this on the frontend?

Answer (score 2):

To primarily answer your second question, I propose to use an established format for repeating schedules, like the [OpenStreetMap Opening Hours](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:opening_hours) format. There's also a [JavaScript library](https://github.com/opening-hours/opening_hours.js) for it.

But since it can also deal with exceptions to the regular schedule, it would probably simplify your model quite a bit, too.